# Is US Speaker Johnson's voting pattern on legislation related to individual freedom consistent with his ideology of 7 Core Principles of Conservatism?

Tags: united-states, congress, conservatism, speaker

In CNN's coverage of the new US House Speaker's "acceptance speech", Speaker [Mike Johnson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Johnson_(Louisiana_politician)) says (after 16:54)

> In his farewell address, President Reagan explained the secret of his rapport with people. And I'd like to paraphrase his explanation all the time.
>
> He said 'you know, they call me the great communicator, but I really wasn't that,' He said 'I was just communicating great things.' And that the same great things that they've got in our nation since its founding.
>
> What are those great things? I call them the seven core principles of American Conservatism. But let me concede to you all. I think it's really quintessentially the core principles of our nation. I boil them down to
>
> - **individual freedom**
> - limited government
> - the rule of law
> - peace through strength
> - fiscal responsibility
> - free markets
> - and human dignity.
>
> Those those are the foundations that made us the extraordinary nation that we are.

Speaker Johnson has been a member of the U.S. House of Representatives from Louisiana's 4th district for almost 7 years, and a member of the Louisiana House of Representatives for almost two years before that. On his house.gov site he elaborates: [7 Core Principles of Conservatism](https://mikejohnson.house.gov/7-core-principles-of-conservatism).

However, I'd like to ask:

**Question:** What are Johnson's actual voting patterns on legislation related to issues of individual freedom?

**update:** As pointed out in comments, it's going to be necessary to avoid making this question about the definition of "individual freedom" *which would be fun* but not suitable here. So let's use Speaker Johnson's own vision from the 7 Core Principles link above as a working definition of individual freedom *for the purposes of this question.*

> 1. Individual Freedom
>
> The birth of our great nation was inspired by the bold declaration that our individual,God-given liberties should be preserved against government intrusion. That same conviction informs our conservative policy decisions still today. In America,we proclaim the self-evident truths that all of us are created equal and granted by God the same inherent freedoms, such as the natural and unalienable rights to life, liberty, conscience, free speech and the free exercise of religion, and the ability to pursue happiness, own property, build wealth and defend ourselves and our families. The purpose of government is to secure these rights, and the ideas we advance should always aim to maintain and increase the liberty of the American people.

Comment: You'll need to define "individual freedom" for the purposes of this question, otherwise it will turn into an argument about "freedom". Republicans like to call a lot of oppressive policies "freedom", particularly around LGBTQ+ issues. For example, his [Louisiana Marriage and Conscience Act](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mike_Johnson_(Louisiana_politician)#Louisiana_Marriage_and_Conscience_Act). Freedom for who to do what?

Comment: @Schwern Hmm... Speaker. Johnson has already done that and I've linked to it. I've made an edit giving that as the working definition for the purposes of this question. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Civil rights and "individual freedom" make this complicated, so I'd need some clairty from you up front. According to his words, his being anti-LGBTQ+ and criminalizing abortion would count *against* his record of "individual freedom". Would you agree? Using his LA Marriage and Conscience Act as an example, does defending the "freedom" to discriminate against others (deny them services and jobs, verbally harass them, etc) count for or against? I'm sure Mike would say they're pro-freedom, his words say they are anti-freedom, what do you want for this question?

Comment: @Schwern I just finished writing an [answer in meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/a/6630/16047) explaining that SE comments should not be used for side discussions. I think you have the makings of an answer - please consider posting as such. *Thanks!*

Comment: This is asking for clarity about your question. I can't write an objective answer without a clear definition of "individual freedom", and that requires clarity around civil rights. His definition does not provide that clarity. Otherwise the answers will be based on the opinions of the authors which will generate plenty of comments.

Comment: @Schwern In that case you may have to pass on this one, or find a way to make your conundrum part of the answer. Answers beginning by asserting something simple like "It depends." do fly here sometimes, especially when they go on to point out carefully why a simple answer is so challenging. But if that's not your style then we can wait to see how others answer.

Comment: I tried. I got to his [anti-vaccination votes](https://www.govtrack.us/congress/bills/117/hr7936) and gave up. How do you count that? Is he protecting soldier's freedom of conscience? Or is he harming soldier's freedom to "defend ourselves and our families" from anti-vax soldiers who may be spreading disease? I think it's the second one, but this is rapidly becoming listing how he vote on issues and making a judgement call. Freedom is complicated. Individual freedoms interact. It ain't as simple as the Speaker says it is.

Comment: Also keep in mind that it is not uncommon for politicians often vote against laws that, at first glance, sound like something that should perfectly align with their stated values. There are a myriad of reasons. Maintaining faction discipline, poison pills and riders, the law not going far enough, competition with their own initiative, procedural or legal concerns, etc.

Comment: @Schwern Take a look at his definition of Human Dignity -- it has some conflicts with Individual Freedom (e.g. the right to life of a fetus trumps the freedom of the mother over her body).

Comment: @Philipp that's a very good point - hopefully answer authors will keep that in mind as well and not just cite some organization's "scorecard".

Comment: I don't have time to write a full answer during work.  However the short TL/DR is that 'freedom' means very different things when viewed from a democratic and republican lens, as both sides believe they should be free to behave in the way they consider and moral and protected from other's interfering with it, but the two sides don't agree with what is 'right' and what behavior should be protected.  I believe viewing it from the POV of the republicans he was speaking to they would mostly say he his voting has backed his claim of freedom; while democrats would vehemently declare the opposite.